# Setting up android to use papertrail in heroku for storing logs

Tags: android, heroku

I was trying to setup android to store logs in heroku using papertrail.

In this documentation it says in step 2 that

> Use the following configuration file, replacing YOUR_HOST & YOUR_PORT
>   with the details shown under the Log Destinations tab in Papertrail.
>   YOUR_APP will appear as the program name in the event viewer.

the Log Destinations is a url but when I click it doesn't show any of the data that it should be displaying.

here is the [link](http://Papertrail%20configuration%20for%20android) for the documentation

I already did step one which is to add the dependencies.

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13' 
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-4' 
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-4' 
compile ('com.papertrailapp:logback-syslog4j:1.0.0'){ 
  exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback' 
}
```